# Error: UnsupportedCharsetException when upload file with MultipartEntity entity

Tags: java, php, android

I send the form to the server, the text from the field and file Edittext.
I think I will send the wrong shape.
This is a form of sending the browser:

```
    POST /wp-content/themes/reverie-master/contacts.php HTTP/1.1
Host: ukp.mogilev.by
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 47504
Origin: http://ukp.mogilev.by
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryH00mEqZ9L5BBl7bz
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://ukp.mogilev.by/elektronnye-obrashcheniya-grazhdan/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: _ym_uid=1478194399500303049; _ym_isad=1; _ym_visorc_28369546=w
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryH00mEqZ9L5BBl7bz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="nameFF"

отправка с пк,тест
------WebKitFormBoundaryH00mEqZ9L5BBl7bz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gorodFF"

отправка с пк,тест
------WebKitFormBoundaryH00mEqZ9L5BBl7bz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="streetFF"

отправка с пк,тест
------WebKitFormBoundaryH00mEqZ9L5BBl7bz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="homeFF"

отправка с пк,тест
------WebKitFormBoundaryH00mEqZ9L5BBl7bz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="contactFF"

q@tut.by
------WebKitFormBoundaryH00mEqZ9L5BBl7bz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="messageFF"

отправка с пк,тест
------WebKitFormBoundaryH00mEqZ9L5BBl7bz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileFF[]"; filename="Instruction 3.1.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryH00mEqZ9L5BBl7bz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileFF[]"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryH00mEqZ9L5BBl7bz--
```

I upload file with help AsyncTask.

```
 private String uploadFile() {
        String responseString = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(UPLOAD_URL);
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        try {


            File filePathstorage = new File(getPath(filePath));//путь к файлу

            filename = filePathstorage.getName();//имя файла

            File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

            //File sendingFile = new File(path, filename);

            FileBody body = new FileBody(filePathstorage, "Content-Type: image/jpeg", filename);

            entity.addPart(KEY_NAME, new StringBody(name));
            entity.addPart(KEY_NASELPUNKT, new StringBody(naselpunkt));
            entity.addPart(KEY_STREET, new StringBody(street));
            entity.addPart(KEY_DOM, new StringBody(house));
            entity.addPart(KEY_EMAIL, new StringBody(e_mail));
            entity.addPart(KEY_MESAGES, new StringBody(message));


            entity.addPart(KEY_IMAGE, body);//  public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "fileFF[]";


            Log.e("RESULT_OTVET_entity", "Response from server: " + entity);
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }
            Log.v("Response for POst", s.toString());


            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(responseString, "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: " + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }

        return responseString;

    }
```

In log i see error:

```
Caused by: java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: IMG_20161115_113532.jpg
```

The error in this line

```
 FileBody body = new FileBody(filePathstorage, "Content-Type: image/jpeg", filename);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change the parameter in FileBody constructor: `FileBody(filePathstorage, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, filename);`

See: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/FileBody.html#constructor_summary

Comment: `Error:
IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed`
in line
`responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);`

Comment: in line
`responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);`

Comment: That's  because you are consuming the response twice. The StringBuilder 's' variable already have the result, so you can do: `responseString = s.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

Seems  `filename` in

```
FileBody body = new FileBody(filePathstorage, "Content-Type: image/jpeg", filename);
```

line interpreted as charset. This is because You probably use old version of Apache HttpClient Mime API.

So try something like that:

```
FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(filename));
```

Comment: FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(filename));
E/RESULT_OTVET: Response from server: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /IMG_20161115_113532.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: You should combine `filePathstorage` and `filename` to get filename with full path to it. Like `new FileBody(new File(filePathstorage + "\" +filename));`. And "отправка с пк,тест" and "name="gorodFF"" - это так мило )

Comment: @ Andriy Omelchenko
you propose to do so
`FileBody body = new FileBody(filePathstorage, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, filename);` but I've already done that, and indicated the error below

Comment: I'm propose `FileBody(new File(filePathstorage + "\" +filename));` - with 1 argument not `FileBody(filePathstorage, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, filename);` - with 3.

Comment: And You use old (probably 4.3 or lower) Apache HttpClient Mime API. Update it, or better get rid of it ([see official documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) and [this](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/FileBody.html#constructor_summary)).

Comment: `FileBody body = new FileBody(new File(filePathstorage + "\"" + filename));`
nothing changed
`E/RESULT_OTVET: Response from server: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraApp/IMG_20161115_113532.jpg"IMG_20161115_113532.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: At first: now You get OTHER exception. And check filename and path to IMG_20161115_11‌​3532.jpg (probably `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraApp/IMG_20161115_113532‌​.jpg"IMG_20161115_11‌​3532.jpg` - is wrong, probably `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraApp/IMG_20161115_113532‌​.jpg` - is correct) and check manually file presence on Android device vie File Explorer.